# Selecting next record from multiple records :SQL

Tags: sql, multiple-records, multirow

I want to select the next record of a WHERE condition is met .

```
EG 
REC  DATA
10   Name1
20   Address1
30   Post1
10   Name2
20   Address2
30   Post2
```

Now my query is

```
select * from table where Data = 'Name1'
```

in the result I want REC20 and rec30 should also be displayed for Name1.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of "next row" unless a column explicitly contains the ordering.  Do you have such a column?  Also, you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Most modern versions of RDBMS have functions like `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to enable you to access next or previous row.

Comment: any simple query solution ?

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing ? Is the DB already designed like this ? Is it a school assignment ?

Comment: `any simple query solution ?` - no, there is no simple solution to this. It's not something you want to be doing anyway.

Comment: @user3855942: Read Gordon's comment. Answer his question.

Comment: these are the only 2 columns @GordonLinoff

Comment: This looks like a traditional data file to me, not like a database table. So there are two main options: 1. Maybe you don't need a database for this, then go on working with a data file instead (where records are implicitly ordered, because you read it line after line). 2. If you want a database, then design your tables properly and convert your data accordingly.

Comment: @user3855942: Then there is nothing that links Name1 to Address1. They are completely unrelated in your database table. (To get an idea about it, make six slips of paper and write a record on each. Then put them in a bucket. Now find a rule which paper to pick for the address belonging to Name1.)